# Get ID from workItem on Azure devops using python

Tags: python, azure, devops

I want to get the ID of specific workItems from multiple projects in Azure DevOPS.

I try the below code

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from azure.devops.v5_1.work_item_tracking.models import Wiql
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

 

pat = 'my_PAT'

organization = 'https://dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJ'
 
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', pat)

connection = Connection(base_url=organization, creds=credentials)
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

tp_query = Wiql(query="""


SELECT [System.Id] FROM workitems WHERE [System.Title] CONTAINS WORDS 'ESA-2525'

""")

 
for plan in wit_client.query_by_wiql(tp_query).work_items:

    print(f"Results for {plan.id}")
```

The error I get is
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\P70252\source\repos\Azure_WIKI_PostUpgrades\Azure_WIKI_PostUpgrades\devops.py", line 15, in

```
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\released\client_factory.py", line 170, in get_work_item_tracking_client

```
return self._connection.get_client('azure.devops.released.work_item_tracking.work_item_tracking_client.WorkItemTrackingClient')
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\connection.py", line 45, in get_client

```
self._client_cache[client_type] = self._get_client_instance(client_class)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\connection.py", line 58, in _get_client_instance

```
url = self._get_url_for_client_instance(client_class)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\connection.py", line 70, in _get_url_for_client_instance

```
resource_areas = self._get_resource_areas()
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\connection.py", line 120, in _get_resource_areas

```
self._resource_areas = location_client.get_resource_areas()
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\v5_1\location\location_client.py", line 107, in get_resource_areas

```
query_parameters=query_parameters)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\client.py", line 77, in _send

```
query_parameters=query_parameters)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\client.py", line 119, in _create_request_message

```
location = self._get_organization_resource_location(location_id)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\client.py", line 160, in _get_organization_resource_location

```
return self._get_resource_location(self.normalized_url, location_id)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\client.py", line 172, in _get_resource_location

```
Client._locations_cache[url] = self._get_resource_locations(url, all_host_types=False)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\client.py", line 208, in _get_resource_locations

```
response = self._send_request(request, headers=headers)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\client.py", line 68, in _send_request

```
self._handle_error(request, response)
```

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\site-packages\azure\devops\client.py", line 291, in _handle_error

```
url=request.url))
```

azure.devops.exceptions.AzureDevOpsAuthenticationError: The requested resource requires user authentication: https://dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJ/_apis

Press any key to continue . . .

The "ESA-2525" is a dummy workitem on which I will replace it with a variable so I can get the ID from different projects.

The connection works, but the wiql does not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

1.package

```
azure-devops==6.0.0b4
```

2. Create full access personal access token
3. code

```
pat = '<token>'

organization = 'https://dev.azure.com/jim0375'

credentials = BasicAuthentication('', pat)

connection = Connection(base_url=organization, creds=credentials)
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

tp_query = Wiql(
    query="SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems WHERE  [System.Title] CONTAINS WORDS 'test'")


for plan in wit_client.query_by_wiql(tp_query).work_items:

    print(f"Results for {plan.id}")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Jim, I upgrade the packet from azure-devops==6.0.0b2 to azure-devops==6.0.0b4 I add my organization and my token (which work) and I get the same error. I have spot the issue on line 13 of your code.

Comment: @yskapell Could you please check if your personal access token have permission to access your organization.

Comment: For a reason my PAT was the issue.